# Communicating to USB port directly from .net application and control the flow of current(on and off)

Tags: c#, .net, usb

I want to communicate to  port directly from .net application and control the flow of current... so that I could directly turn on or off a step-motor or anything from the c# program. Basically I want to use USB ports like serial ports...I also want to know how this can be done using arduino.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Share what you've tried so far, and explain what problem you've encountered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use the `SerialPort`from `System.IO.Ports`. As for the arduino, use `Serial` static class to write / read the port.

Here is a little sketch illustrating how you can proceed (with a windows forms application).

**.NET** (txtCom As `TextBox` and btnSend As `Button`)

```
Imports System.IO.Ports
Public Class SerialCom
    Dim WithEvents SP As New SerialPort("COM5", 9600)
    Private Sub SerialCom_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SP.Open()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SP_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SP.DataReceived
        Dim dataR As String = SP.ReadExisting
        Me.Invoke(New updateText(AddressOf updateText_s), dataR)
    End Sub

    Public Delegate Sub updateText(ByVal line As String)
    Sub updateText_s(ByVal line As String)
        txtCom.AppendText(line)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
        SP.Write("Welcome")
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Arduino**

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setTimeout(200); // Wait 200ms max. when Serial.readString() is called
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("CONNECTION");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("+OK");
  delay(1000);
  String rec;
  rec=Serial.readString();
  Serial.println("Received:'"+rec+"'"); // Send back what we received
}
```

NOTES: To check the COM port ID, you can *{CTRL}+{BEAK}* on Windows then open the Device Manager and look for your Arduino under PORT subtree. Don't forget to connect your arduino before starting the .NET app.

Serial communication on Arduino : https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/